# Java Zip File custom names

Tags: java, zip

```
zipFile.addFile(myFile, parameters);
```

Zip file creation in java by default adds the file name as zip enty in zip file Instead of adding file to zipfile like this, how to add file with custom name?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are asking but if you are using Java 7, use the new ZIP filesystem instead:

```
final Path zipfile = Paths.get("/path/to/your.zip");
finam URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:" + zipfile.toAbsolutePath());
final Map<String, String> env = Collections.emptyMap();

final Path fileOnDisk = Paths.get("path/to/file/on/disk");

try (
    final FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
) {
    final Path fileInZip = zipfs.getPath("path/wanted/into/zip");
    Files.copy(fileOnDisk, fileInZip, StandardCopyOption.CREATE);
}
```